# PI controller for LLC converter does not work under all conditions

Tags: pid-controller, llc-converter

I used this [paper](https://ietresearch.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1049/iet-pel.2019.1503) as a reference. I am simulating a half-bridge LLC (350V-400V input to 12V output) with a PI controller. You can find the MATLAB Simulink model I have [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IjEZANLnx5RAYyqGbYKEBexwvlQwMxY_/view?usp=sharing). All the parameters are taken from the paper. For the PI controller, Kp = 50000 and Ki = 1000.

I have 4 conditions to check if the PI controller works.

1. Heavy load (23A) @ 400V
2. Heavy load (23A) @ 350V
3. Light load (6.3A) @ 400V
4. Light load (6.3A) @ 350V

This system works under condition 1,3,4 but not 2. I checked that the converter if switching at around 51kHz can give the output voltage to be close to 12V. So my PI controller is not working.
I can see that the output from the PI controller gives negative frequency. Here is the model in Simulink. You can see the frequency is negative at the very bottom of the screenshot.

[image]

Parameters from the paper:

[image]

**My questions**: Can I have any suggestion how to fix this problem? My ultimate goal is to design a conventional PI controller for LLC converter.

Comment: Could you please put the tank component values? I couldn't see from the sim schematic, if you did.

Comment: I updated the post with all the values I used in the model. Thanks.

Comment: Error is negative in your example. Isn't it supposed to be positive i.e. E = ref - Y *(ref = 12, Y is the output voltage)*? Can you try and see what happens, please? Also you need to limit the minimum frequency to somewhere above the pole frequency which is set by (Lr+Lm) and Cr in order to prevent operation in capacitive mode.

Comment: I will check this  again. Thanks